# How to print Logo stored in Epson Printer using JavaPOS

Tags: epson, receipt, javapos

Want to know, how to print Logo stored in Epson Printer (TM-T88V) using JavaPOS, I used Epson Utility to store logo image in printer. I am using JavaPOS, POS is able to print receipt. I want to print logo on top but no luck. I tried to make some changes in Java file.
Any help will be great. Do i need specific code to add or i need to make change in jpos.xml.

Thanks

Comment: [tag:logo] is a programming language.  Please don't use it's tag for questions relating to graphical logos.

Comment: Dear friend, I have a Vega7000 Series  EFT-POS terminal. Do you have any idea how can I develop program for it? What kind of tools and IDEs and Documents am I need? Where can I find this requirements? And does it have JVM? i.e. does it support Java applications or I must use another programming language? Any light on this issue highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to print pre-loaded logos you have to use directIO method with PTR_DI_PRINT_FLASH_BITMAP2 const.

Example (32 32 pre-loaded logo keycode):

```
String myobject = Integer.toString(POSPrinterConst.PTR_BM_CENTER);
int[] data = new int[]{0};
data[0] += 32;                          // LSB
data[0] += 32 << 16;                    // MSB
 
ptr.directIO(EpsonPOSPrinterConst.PTR_DI_PRINT_FLASH_BITMAP2, data, myobject);
```

Answer (score 0):

For an image stored into NVRAM:

```
// This will print the image stored in position 2
ptr.directIO(EpsonPOSPrinterConst.PTR_DI_PRINT_FLASH_BITMAP, new int[]{2}, Integer.valueOf(POSPrinterConst.PTR_BM_CENTER).toString());
```

Where

[image: PTR_DI_PRINT_FLSH_BITMAP]

Alternatively it is possible to load images when you are runing the program

To register a bitMap you can do:

```
POSPrinterControl114 ptr = (POSPrinterControl114)new POSPrinter();
ptr.setBitmap(1, POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, "/path/to/file.bmp", ptr.getRecLineWidth() / 2), POSPrinterConst.PTR_BM_CENTER);
```

and when you want to print it:

```
ptr.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, "\u001b|1B");
```

If you want`setBitmap` store images in NVRAM you must change property `"UsedNVRAM"` in your TM-T88V.xml file

```
<prop name="UsedNVRAM" type="String" value="1"/>
```

Or mark the checkbox on SetupPos app.
One problem is that this methods can't be mixed, for example, if you store images to NVRAM with setBitmap, you will not be able to print anything with directIO method

Anyway, I recommend to take a look into documentation folder when you download [JavaPOS ADK, 1.14.18](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=soft&scat=40)

Answer (score -2):

You need to use something similar to the below:

```
ptr.printBitmap(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,YOUR_LOGO_PATH, POSPrinterConst.PTR_BM_ASIS, POSPrinterConst.PTR_BM_CENTER);
```

Does it work?